# How can I get the MySQL super_read_only setting to work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I can't seem to get the new super_read_only configuration option to work. Logged in as root or a user with SUPER privileges, I can still insert a row. If the user doesn't have super privileges, I get the correct error that the server is running with the -read-only option. Here is an example:

```
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.10                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1                |
| version                 | 5.7.10-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%read_only%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| innodb_read_only | OFF   |
| read_only        | ON    |
| super_read_only  | ON    |
| tx_read_only     | OFF   |
+------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into repl1 (value) values ('this should not work');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from repl1 where value like '%should not%';
+----+----------------------+
| id | value                |
+----+----------------------+
|  6 | this should not work |
+----+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are running 5.7.8 (or later)?  File a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a consequence of [MySQL Bug#79328](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79328).  I'm assuming you started MySQL Server with either command-line or configuration file options to enable `--super_read_only` mode.  Because of the referenced bug, the `--super_read_only` option is not properly processed at server startup.  Until this is fixed (hopefully soon!), `--super_read_only` must to be set dynamically.